# Нужна ли точка после подзаголовка с местом и временем действия?

Tags: пунктуация, заголовок

Если художественный текст предваряется подзаголовком с местом и временем действия (например, "Лондон, 1956 год"), нужно ли ставить после него точку?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

> **7.** В конце заголовков точка не ставится, независимо от их структуры (односоставное номинативное предложение, двусоставное и т. д.)...

Нет разницы, название это газетной статьи или книги, заголовок это или подзаголовок, — точка в конце не ставится.
***Лондон, 1956 год***

**Примеры**

• "Севастопольские рассказы" (цикл из трех рассказов Л. Н. Толстого):
Севастополь в декабре месяце
Севастополь в мае
*Севастополь в августе 1855 года*

• Ф. М. Достоевский:
*Дневник писателя. 1880 год*
(Но: *Дневник писателя за 1877 г.* — точка принадлежит сокращению.)

• Артур Конан Дойл (публицистика):
*Британская кампания во Франции и Фландрии. 1914 год*

[Знаки препинания в газетных и журнальных заголовках](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168)